# Determinant and a straight line equation

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, determinant

I know that if we put vectors in rows and calculate the determinant we get the volume of a parallelogram.

I have read the following example:

> Find the straight line equation that goes through the points $(1,2),(3,-5)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ using Determinant.

How should I approach it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

Comment: I'd rather say *area*.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the vector $\vec{v}=(1,2)-(3,-5)=(-2,7)$ is a parallel vector to the line. Let's call $A (1,2)$ and $B$ $(3,5)$. Now, for a random point $M(x,y)$ on the line, $\vec{AM}=(x-1,y-2)$ and $\vec{v}=(-2,7)$ are parallel (colinear), hence their determinant must be zero. So $7(x-1)+2(y-2)=0$. This way uses determinant, there are many other ways!

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions 


1. why is $(-2,7)$ is a parallel vector to the line?


2. why $\vec{AM}=(x-1,y-2)$ is parallel to $(-2,7)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply express that the the two given points and an arbitrary point on the line are collinear, hence form a parallelogram of no area:

$$\left|\begin{matrix}x&1&3\\y&2&\bar5\\1&1&1\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}x-1&3-1\\y-2&\bar5-2\end{matrix}\right|=0.$$